# Does Apache Beam stateful Processing consider window lateness constraints (withAllowedLateness) for resetting state?

Tags: streaming, apache-flink, apache-beam, stateful

I'm trying to implement a valueState to filter records in my ParDo transformation. The high level flow is this:

1. Fixed-Window of 1hr size, with allowedLateness (10min)
2. The first message (for a given key) that is processed in the ParDo shall set the valueState(boolean) to true. Subsequent messages for the same key shall be dropped if corresponding valueState is set to true. (Allow only first message for a given key in every window).
3. The messages (that are not dropped in step 2) will be written out as output.

While testing this however, I see that, after the Fixed window time-period ends (1hr), the state is reset/lost. Ideally, the state should be available to process late records until allowedLateness period (10min is complete).

Comment: How are you emitting the state value, are you trying to access it with OnWindowExpiration method https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.25.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.OnWindowExpiration.html?

Answer (score 0):

These parts are right:

- Each 1 hour window expires when the watermark reaches the end of the hour plus 10 minutes.
- For a given window, the state is cleaned up after the window expires.

Here are the parts that I have corrections

- State is never reset.
- Elements with timestamps in different windows are processed totally independently. Many windows may be receiving data at the same time. Each hour window *happened* after another, when the data was generated. But it is *not* processed after the other.
- Allowed lateness will not cause elements from a later window to be processed using the state from the prior window. It will simply allow the state to stay longer and the elements to not be dropped.